# Trouble animating sprites (Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a school project with pygame and have unfortunately run into trouble with animating my sprites, or more specifically, changing the sprite from one to another, and I'm unsure on how to do it. Currently, I have a class of my spaceship sprite and background sprite:

```
game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'img')
space_background = pygame.image.load('background.png').convert()
starship_1 = pygame.image.load('starship2.png').convert()
starship_2 = pygame.image.load('starship3.png').convert()
starship_3 = pygame.image.load('starship4.png').convert()


class starship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(starship_1, (150,150))
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (400, 400)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
BackGround = background()
StarShip = starship()
all_sprites.add(BackGround)
all_sprites.add(StarShip)
```

My while loop looks like this:

```
run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and StarShip.rect.x > 25:  
        StarShip.rect.x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and StarShip.rect.x < 600:  
        StarShip.rect.x += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and StarShip.rect.y > 25: 
        StarShip.rect.y -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and StarShip.rect.y < 600:
        StarShip.rect.y += vel

    
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    all_sprites.update()
    all_sprites.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update() 
    
pygame.quit()
```

This has basic movement of left/right/up/down. What I want to do is have my StarShip object constantly change between the variables starship_1, starship_2, starship_3 (which contain my 3 sprites of my starship), so it looks like the starship is moving.

My sprites look like this:

[image: StarShip1]

[image: Starship2]

[image: Starship3]

As you can see, it is the engine fire that is the difference between those sprites. How would I change between those 3 sprites every 1 second?

FYI: When the program is launched, this is what appears:[image: Startup Picture]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to achieve this effect.

1. Create a function to change image of the sprite. ( Easy Task)
2. Call the above function periodically every x seconds. ( Intermediate Task)

Step 1.
You can achieve this by just setting/loading the self.image variable with the next image.

Step 2.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

time_counter = 0
images = ['starship_1', 'starship_2', 'starship_3']
current_img_index = 0

while run:    
    # Your Code

    time_counter = clock.tick()

    # 1000 is milliseconds == 1 second. Change this as desired
    if time_counter > 1000:
        # Incrementing index to next image but reseting back to zero when it hits 3
        current_img_index = (current_img_index + 1) % 3 
        set_img_function(current_img_index) # Function you make in step 1

        # Reset the timer
        time_counter = 0
```

A good approach will be to complete step 1 and then bind it to a button. Test if it works and then move on to step 2.

Some good read about the functions used in this code to fully understand them is [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)

Comment: thank you, great idea, it works with just modifying it so that a variable increases with the time_counter variable until it reaches 1000, and then it'll be reset and your if statement kicks in. I did this because my time_counter never reached above 1000, it'd only stick to around 30-35.